# Define variables with "{}object", unexpected TypeError

Tags: javascript

If `{}object`, e.g. `{}"string"`, `{}[1, 2, 3]`, or `{}({})` is exactly equal (according to `===`) to `object`, e.g. `"string"`, `[1, 2, 3]`, or `({})`, why can you define a variable with the latter but not the former?

To clarify:

```
{}"string" === "string" // true
var a = "string"        // No error
var a = {}"string"      // SyntaxError: Unexpected string
var a = ({}"string")    // SyntaxError: Unexpected string
var a = {}("string")    // TypeError: object is not a function
var a = ({}("string"))  // TypeError: object is not a function
```

Comment: This is an excellent question, by the way.

Comment: I never understand why people think these are great questions.  What do they have to do with any real code that someone would actually write?

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess at least it was asked very clearly with examples, even though it's not really useful.

Comment: @jfriend00 It made me realize that there was a quirk in Javascript that I had never thought about before.

Comment: @PeterOlson - and what usefulness was that quirk?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's useless, but I'm not a vile pragmatist who thinks things have to be useful to be interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, the `{}` seems to be behaving like an empty block, not as an object literal.  So think of it syntactically like:

```
// Valid syntax...
// despite confusing whitespace...
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {}"string" === "string";
```

However, that empty block cannot be used on the right side of an assignment like

```
var a = {}"string"; //SyntaxError
```

And here, the `{}()` implies that `{}` is being used as a function, with parameters inside `()`

```
var a = {}("string")    // TypeError: object is not a function
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and clearly explained answer. I had totally forgotten about arbitrary blocks (as they have no uses to my knowledge.) I assumed `{}` was acting as a magic constructor akin to `new Object` but instead producing literals. Clearly my knowledge of the intricacies of JavaScript is very limited.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, as in C++, you can have code blocks arbitrarily placed in the program. Since Javascript does not have block scope, as C++ does, this is basically useless in Javascript.

Here is an example of a non-empty code block:

```
{
  //this is a code block
  var a = 1;
  var b = a + 1;
}
alert(a);  // 1
alert(b);  // 2
```

Note that **these lonely code blocks are not expressions**, so it is not possible to put them inside of a statement. This explains why `var a = {}"string"` and other uses of it inside of a statement are not syntactically valid.

`{}"string" === "string"` returns `true` in a console because `{}` is an empty code block, which is ignored, followed by `"string" === "string"`, which is obviously `true`. If you use whitespace like this, the code is clearer:

```
{
  //empty code block
}
"string" === "string"
```

Inside of an expression, `{}` is interpreted as an object literal. If you try something like `{}()` it will complain that `{}` is not a function.

Comment: Aha, I was not aware of this feature of Javascript. Now I know why `{}` in the console evaluates to `undefined`. Any particular reason why after you surround the braces with parenthesis it is treated as an object literal?

Comment: @Ian If you put parentheses around some code in Javascript, it tells the parser to interpret what is inside of the parentheses as an expression. Lonely code blocks cannot be placed inside of an expression, so it has to be an object literal.